# Freeze Windows XP Embedded if HP Thin Client is running 2 days - root of problem is in Z partition?

Tags: freeze, thin-client, windows-xp-embedded

Hello we use  HP Thin Client T5740 I would like disable Z partion or HP RAM DISK manager because if thin client is running 2 days Windows XP Embedded freezes. I checked the Z partion and it was full I belivie that the root of  problem with freezing Windows is in Z partion.

If windows freeze I restart thin client and it cleaned Z partion than is everything OK.

Thank for your feedback

Comment: What is the Z partition being used for? It sounds like temp space for XP embedded. Anyways, if it's cleared on reboot, you could schedule a daily reboot during off-business hours.

Answer (score 0):

You will need this for storing your TEMP and TMP folders, but there are workarounds:

1. Change the location of TEMP or TMP folders

   - Go to My Computer → right-click → select Properties → Advanced System Settings → Environment Variables
   - In here you will find your TEMP and TMP variables are pointing at the Z: drive
   - Simply change the variables from Z: to C:, then reboot the thin client. You will find your TEMP and TMP will have been relocated to the C: drive and you will have no problems.
2. Increase the Ramdisk size

   - As you are using HP T5740 which is WES2009, you can only set it to 96 MB. If this is not enough, then you will need to use the above method.

FYI, the new WES7 SP1 can go up to 1 GB of RAMDISK.